# Service Bus queues with Java not always read events

Tags: java, azure, queue, message-queue, servicebus

I have a strange problem with this queue. When I use it, even when I see on Microsoft azure site that there is an event in queue, it not always read it. For example, 4 times I get message null, and 5th time message is ok. It works, but not always. I learned from this site: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/.

And here is my code (almost the same as on the site). I also use Jackson to serialize.:

```
Configuration config =
            ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(
                    engineConfiguration.getServiceBusNamespace(),
                    engineConfiguration.getServiceBusPolicyName(),
                    engineConfiguration.getServiceBusSasKeyValue(),
                    ".servicebus.windows.net"
            );

    ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);

    try
    {
        ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
        opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);

        ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM =
                service.receiveQueueMessage(engineConfiguration.getServiceBusQueueName(), opts);
        Something somethingObject = mapper.readValue(resultQM.getValue().getBody(), Something.class);
        service.deleteMessage(resultQM.getValue());
        return somethingObject;
    }
    catch (ServiceException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this issue may be caused by service bus queue lock time, we can set the lock duration in the service bus queue CONFIGURE tab, the following screenshot is the details:
[image]

If your code throw some exception before "deleteMessage()" method, the queue message will be locked (the queue length in azure portal will contains this lock message), we can get this message again after the lock duration time.